# KanBan view inherit with QCode

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-13

I am trying to customize the kanban view on res.partner

I want to list all category_id associated to the contact **without** using

```
<field name="category_id"  widget="many2many_tags" options="{'color_field': 'color', 'no_create_edit': True}" />
```

I tried to use the Qwep t-foreach loop but doesn't work, why?

```
<li t-foreach="record.category_id" t-as="item">
    <t t-esc="item_value"/>
</li>
```

this print

```
many2many

false

false

[object Object]

false

false

res.users

false

true

false

true

Venditore

[object Object]

7,6

2record
```

i need to print the name of the res.partner.category

at the same time i need to create a class inside each kanban box with the name of each category_id
something like

```
<div class="oe_kanban_details category_1 category_2">
 ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over record `category_id` attributes. You got that result because you used the special variable [$as_value](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/qweb.html#loops), those are the actual values of the following attributes.

```py
type
change_default
company_dependent
context
depends
domain
manual
readonly
relation
required
searchable
sortable
store
string
views
raw_value
value
```

The [raw_value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/kanban/kanban_record.js#L571) contains the recordset `ids` and the [value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/field_utils.js#L290) is a string showing the number of records.

You can try to override the kanban record qweb context to get the `category_id` data `[{'color':, 'display_name':, 'id': }, ...]` from `recordData` object.

***Example***

```
var KanbanRecord = require('web.KanbanRecord');

KanbanRecord.include({
     _get_M2M_data: function (field) {
        var categories = [];
        if (field in this.recordData && this.recordData[field].data) {
            categories = this.recordData.category_id.data;
        }
        return categories;
     },
     _setState: function (recordState) {
        var self = this;
        this._super(recordState);
        self.qweb_context['get_m2m_data'] = self._get_M2M_data.bind(self);
    },
});
```

Then use it in kanban view  like following:

```
<t t-foreach="get_m2m_data('category_id')" t-as="category_data">
    <t t-esc="category_data.data['display_name']"/>
</t>
```

Use the following code to get a similar result when using the field tag:

```
<div class="o_kanban_tags_section oe_kanban_partner_categories">
    <span class="oe_kanban_list_many2many">
        <div class="o_field_many2manytags o_field_widget o_kanban_tags">
            <t t-foreach="get_m2m_data('category_id')" t-as="category_data">
                <span t-att-class="'o_tag o_tag_color_'+ category_data.data['color']"><span></span><t t-esc="category_data.data['display_name']"/>
                </span>
            </t>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All quite clear i'll study it. Just one thing, showing data inside this.recordData i cannot see my custom fields (one of theese many2many) created on res.partner why?